# VLC error too many open files and missing plugins?

Tags: vlc

Ubuntu 18.04 ...
main warning cannot load module `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/demux/libnsv_plugin.so' (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/demux/libnsv_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files

Lots of modules could not be found in the demux folder but they do exist. Can't use VLC for more than a few seconds. Can anyone please suggest something ?

Comment: `ldd $(which vlc)`  and `snap list` please.

Comment: Sorry I removed and installed an earlier version.